# How can I remove all css references to a component made with stenciljs?

Tags: typescript, web-component, stenciljs, tsx

I build a login component with stenciljs and when I remove it from the dom when switching components it works correctly, but the css reference remains in the head tag of the html file.

Is there a way to remove the component next to the css file referenced in the decorator@component styleUrl ?
thank you

my component with its css reference

```
import { Component, h, State,Listen,Element,EventEmitter,Event } from '@stencil/core';
 

@Component({
  tag: 'wc-component',
  styleUrl: 'Component.css',
  shadow: false,
})
```

when I change to the wc-component2 component in the html, the css of the already removed component that was wc-component in the example is kept

```
<style sty-id="sc-wc-component">
```